# Как можно узнать температуру видеокарты в Python

Tags: python, gpu, видеокарта

С помощью какой библиотеки можно узнать температуру видеокарты в Python?
Видеокарта - NVidia 1080
Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. использовать CUDA
2. под windows можно обратиться к wmi
3. использувать чужой велосипед. например такой https://github.com/anderskm/gputil

Comment: Tatarincev gputil позволяет с помощью GPU.showUtilization(all=True) вывести таблицу с параметрами GPU , в том числе о температуре. Как получить только значение температуры?

Comment: посмотрите код. там же все просто. после получения экземпляра GPU, можете использовать GPU.temperature